# Proxies not created when publish function app

Tags: azure, arm, azure-function-app, proxies, azure-functions-core-tools

I have created a function app with ARM template and deployed my functions with Azure Functions Core Tools:

```
func azure functionapp publish myfunctionapp
```

Now, when I add proxies.json file and deploy again my functionapp with above command it seems that proxies are not been deployed and so not showed in Proxies section on Portal.

If I try to run the functionapp locally with `func start`, both functions and proxies work.

Why are proxies not deployed to the function app?
Is there any setting in function app that I have to enable so the proxies can be deployed?

I have also tried with a devops task(function app deploy) but still not working.

Any idea?